# Botón guardar como

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap

Estoy intentando añadir a una aplicación web que estoy realizando la funcionalidad de descargar un archivo guardándolo donde desee el usuario. Sería una especie de `guardar como...`

¿Hay algún tipo de framework con el que se pueda realizar esto? Para realizar la aplicación web estoy utilizando php, html5, jquery y bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad no creo que puedas forzarlo, eso ya depende de los navegadores web, en Chrome por ejemplo viene desactivado por default la opción de preguntar donde guardar al clickear en "descargar" por ejemplo, si activas esa opción te va a mostrar el diálogo.

Te diriges a `Configuración>Mostrar configuración avanzada...>Descargas` y ahí trae un `check` en el cual habilitas o deshabilitas la opción de preguntar donde guardar, ahí puedes comprobarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Igual puedes revisar la respuesta de este usuario que preguntó lo mismo, no la coloqué aquí porque no se si en verdad funciona:

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336663/how-to-make-a-browser-display-a-save-as-dialog-so-the-user-can-save-the-conten)

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar la librería FileSaver.js que te proporciona precisamente esa funcionalidad. Soporta todos los navegadores principales excepto versiones de Internet Explorer anteriores a la 10.

[FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

[FileSaver.js demo](https://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un elemento  y agregarle las clases de botones de bootstrap y usar la propiedad download para la descarga

```
<a href="mifile.jpg" class="btn btn-primary" download="mi-imagen.jpg">
 Descargar
</a>
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar tan rápido. Este código descarga el fichero que se indique (en este caso la foto) pero lo descarga en la carpeta que tenga el usuario por defecto en el navegador para guardar las descargas. Lo que pretendía hacer es que aparezca la típica ventana donde se puede escoger la ruta donde quiera el usuario guardar el fichero. ¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

Answer (score 1):

No se si te entiendo bien, pero eso se puede hacer siempre con el click derecho. El usuario selecciona donde guardar lo que tiene debajo del puntero del ratón y listo. Porque una **aplicación web** es algo que se ejecuta en el navegador, por lo que el navegador en principio ya ofrece la opción de guardar como. Si me aclaras un poco más lo que quieres hacer y de donde partimos cuando dices aplicación web, quizás te pueda ayudar más.